# How to test if Json response includes error or proper json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Explanation: Throughout app, we use a web request method located in AppDelegate.m to fetch data from server. I use a token in all these requests. Sometimes the response from server is the json : {error = "token_not_provided"} or {error = "token_expired"}. I need a way to test if the json includes these errors or the proper json data. If the data sent back is either of these errors, we need to go back to login screen to get a new token upon login. Right now, I have no way to detect these errors in the request method so if they occur, the app will forever crash because there is no way to take you back to login. Here is the request method in App Delegate:

```
-(void)makeRequest:(NSString*)urlString method:(NSString*)method params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onComplete:(RequestBlock)callback {

// create the url
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", BASE_URL, urlString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];

    NSString *token = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

    if(!token){

        token = @"NO_TOKEN";



    }


    // set the method (GET/POST/PUT/UPDATE/DELETE)
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request addValue:[@"Bearer " stringByAppendingString:token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


// if we have params pull out the key/value and add to header
    if(params != nil) {
         NSMutableString * body = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSString * key in params.allKeys) {
            NSString * value = [params objectForKey:key];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, value];
    }
        [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// submit the request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, 
NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                           // do we have data?
                           if(data && data.length > 0) {

                               NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                               // if we have a block lets pass it
                               if(callback) {
                                   callback(json);


                             }

                               HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO TEST IF WE HAVE ERROR JSON or PROPER JSON


                           }


    }];
```

}

Comment: if([[data valueForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"token_not_provided"] || [[data valueForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"token_expired"]) {

  I can't use this to test because it will crash if it contains proper json

}

Comment: Don't add additional information in a comment. [Edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: You can cast the `NSURLResponse` to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and check the http status code. Token errors are mostly `401`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the interface on your server you could send a bool to identify if the request was successful. Something like "success" = 1 or 0.

To check on the error-message is dangerous, if the message changes your app will crash. If you want to do it anyway you need to check if the key "error" exists and then what it contains.

```
// Check if key is available.
if ([json.keys containsObject:@"error"]) {
    if ([json[@"error"] isEqualToString:@"token_not_privided"] || [json[@"error"] isEqualToString:@"token_expired"]) {
        // Token is invalid
    } else {
        // Something different went wrong.
    }
}
// Nothing is wrong, lets inform the caller. 
else {
    if (callback) {
        callback(json);
    }
}
```

You should check on the json and not on the data.